# How to make UIcollectionview not to scroll first page when call reloaddata and pageEnable = yes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use UIPageControl and make UICollectionView.pagingEnabled =YES.
scroll to the second page, and tap a button which will call 'reloadData' method of collectionview.
The collectionview scroll to the first page,But I want collectionView still keep the second page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your button action method after the line "reloadData" method call

```
 [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath //in your example second page index path 
                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                        animated:YES];
```